# Managing the loading and unloading of 300 to 500 images in an iOS App

Tags: ios, image

We are in the process of building an iOS app for creating a large digital catalog. On average the app will need to manage 300 to 500 images. These images graphically represent the item being offered and appear along side the description. The Android version of this app is complete and works as required.

The app requires 2 images for each item. A thumbnail for the list and a pic that is presented with the item description. The thumbnail is pre-processed to the needed size and presented with the list. It is not a separate pic created by the user and loaded.

Memory seems to be an issue as well, particularly with some of the early iPads that only came with 512 MB of RAM making the early models effectively useless unless we can find a better way to manage pics.

Currently when the app starts, the images are uploaded from a folder on a Windows server and temporarily held in cache. For the item list we have tried the load several above and several below approach but the speed is just not acceptable. We have attempted managing the size of the images, that helps but not significantly.

As I am new to this, I am attempting to find a more efficient way to manage the pics so the user does not experience the wait. I know that it has to exist.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance...

Comment: checkout my answer. if not worked then let me know i will help you out to solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use third party library like SDWebImage to load image from URL.

You can write like this to load image from URL :

```
[myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PROFILE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];
```

Now set below code in your view controller viewdidload() or viewwillAppear() Method.

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];
[[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] setShouldDecompressImages:NO];
```

i hope this will work for you.

Comment: I'm using the "SimpleImageCache", which I said to use 200M on the disk, and 100M for the memory Size, if there device has more than 512M of Ram, or 1M if there is less than 512M Ram (for the older iPads).  Before sticking it in the Cache, I'm resizing the image to max of screenSize/4 for the thumbnail, and screensize/2 for the main picture. I also Modified the UITableViewController, that on the first load it ignores the pictures, because it is trying to instantiate all the cells on the first load instead of only the ones currently visible. After I initialize 10 above and below visible.

Comment: once you try with SdwebImage i hope you got result as u want.